# `using` as typedef causes CS1001

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, typedef, using

What's wrong with

```
using T = int;
```

?

It causes compiler-error `CS 1001 Identifier expected`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to write

```
using T = System.Int32;
```

because `int` is just a shorthand for `System.Int32`, and those shorthands are not implemented in the language specification (i.e., `int` is not an identifier according to the specs). You need to give the full qualified name.